# Changing a tag when one function is passed into another using UpValues

Tags: programming, upvalues

I have two complicated functions `f[x,y]` and `g[t]`.

Before the main evaluation code in `g[expr]`, I run some computationally expensive tests to check that `expr` has correct syntax.  If `expr` does not have correct syntax, it gives an error to the user.  But otherwise, it continues.

Now, the output of `f[x,y]` can be used as input of `g` (as in `g[f[x,y]]`).  The result of `f[x,y]` is usually very *very* complicated, but *always* has correct syntax for the function `g`. Thus to save time I want to bypass the computationally expensive but pointless checks in `g`.

For this I invented a tag: `$needsErrorChecking`, which is supposed to by switched to `False` if `f` and `g` are called in the nested form `g[f[x,y]]`.  Otherwise it is `True`, in which case the error checking routines take place.

Here is my toy example:

```
Clear[f, g]
 f[x_, y_] := x + y

$needsErrorChecking = True;
    g[f[z__]] ^:= "Nothing" /; ($needsErrorChecking = False);
    g[t_] := Module[{variables}, Print[$needsErrorChecking];
   If[$needsErrorChecking,(*Complicated Code*) Null, $needsErrorChecking = True]; 2*t];
```

However, Running

```
g[f[x, y]]
```

yields `True` and `2(x+y)`.  So it gives the correct answer, but the error checking code isn't bypassed.  What can I do to fix this?

Or, is there a totally different way to go about accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 1):

If the special case that does not deserve checks comes only out of function `f`, then I would try the following code instead of using tags. The basic idea is to use the head of the unevaluated expression as the "tag".

```
SetAttributes[g, HoldFirst];
g[f[z__]] := (Print["no checks here"]; Sqrt[f[z]]);
g[t_] := (Print["checks here"]; Sqrt[t]);
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2
```

The output of `g[4]` and `g[f[1,2]]` yield respectively the expected checking version and non-checking version.

If the special case that does not deserve checks comes from more than a handful of functions, I would use something based on `OptionsPattern`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your scheme work by setting the `HoldAll` attribute on `g`:

```
SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]
```

Without it, `g[f[x, y]]` evaluates the `f` expression before `g` gets a chance to look at it.  Thus, the `"Nothing"` definition never kicks in and `$needsErrorChecking` is never cleared.

**Alternative**

A simpler way to achieve this effect is as follows:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := x + y

SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]

g[t_f] := fastG[t]
g[t_] := Module[{variables}, Print@"perform check"; fastG[t]]
fastG[t_] := 2 * t
```

Then:

```
g[f[1, 2]]

(* 6 *)
```

and:

```
g[3]

(*
   perform check
   6
*)
```